# AngularJS ng-bind value or placeholder

Tags: angularjs

Here's my relevant code:

```
   <td data-ng-bind="item.value"></td>
```

What if there is no value for a respective item and I wanted a placeholder instead, eg. 'N/A'

Unfortunately this does not seem to work:

```
   <td data-ng-bind="item.value || 'N/A'"></td>
```

I better show the whole code because I do not think an ng-if will work in my case:

```
      <tr ng-repeat="doc in supportDocRefList.docs track by $index">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="column in supportDocRefList.schema.fields" ng-switch on="column.type">
          <p ng-switch-when="Date" data-ng-bind="doc[column.name] | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' || 'N/A'"></p>
          <p ng-switch-when="textarea" ng-bind-html="doc[column.name]"></p>
          <p ng-switch-default data-ng-bind="doc[column.name]"></p>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

**Thanks Maando:**

```
<p ng-switch-when="Date" data-ng-bind="doc[column.name] || 'N/A' | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'"></p>
```

Comment: that should work, which version of angular are you using. Why not try with <td>{{item.value || 'N/A'}}</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that filter should come later.. i.e. the default value should come before the filter.

```
 <p ng-switch-when="Date" data-ng-bind="doc[column.name] || 'N/A'" | date:'MM-dd-yyyy' ></p>
```